# Using wildcards with Windows "Copy" and strings of varying length?

Tags: command-prompt, batch-rename

I have a file named `!Template - Year End Report.doc`.

I'm trying to use the following command:

```
copy !Template* customer_name*
```

The result is `customer_nameear End Report.doc`.

If I use a shorter name, like this:

```
copy !Template* cust1*
```

Then I get this output: `cust1late - Year End Report.doc`

How can I make it replace "!Template" with the customer name, regardless of length?

Comment: I've no idea of what you are trying to do, but please read [copy](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html). You can't have wildcards in the destination name.

Comment: Obviously you can.  If you do `copy !template* customer` the new file is literally named `customer`.  However, if you use a wildcard in the destination, as I did in the question, you get completely different results.

Comment: Exactly. The behaviour is undefined if you have a wildcard in the destination name. The syntax for copy is `copy source1 + source2.. destination [options]`. You can replace the sources with a wildcard but not the destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no chance to do it with just `copy`. Use a `for` to split the filenames:

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=-" %a in ('dir /b !Template*') do @echo copy "%a-%b" "cust -%b"
```

(to use in a batchfile, use `%%a` and `%%b` instead of `%a` and `%b`)

Comment: That's too bad. I swear I used to do this all the time in DOS with copy.  Writing a batch file is a bit out of the scope. I was hoping to use Excel to generate all the copy strings based on an existing column of all my customers.

Comment: well - your question is tagged "batch-file"... - Anyway: it's just one line. Use it on command line or put it into a batchfile - no big issue. (remove the `echo` to arm the `copy` command)

Comment: I'd have to iterate through each customer name somehow though, which would add another loop and reading a source.

Comment: how to decide which customer name to use instead of `!Template`? Another loop and reading from a (text)file is not a big issue in batch.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely within my capabilities, but there are only like 15 customers. I literally could have manually renamed all the files by now.  It was more of a "Hey, I should be able to do copy with wildcards" that turned into a curiosity about the behavior.  I digress.